# dynamic linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

If I have Book entity with properties Id, Title, ISBN, Tag. Inside winform window user can input search text and from combobox choose ByTitle, ByISBN, ByTag search options.

on button click event those values are taken as

```
var comboSelection = (comboBox1.SelectedItem ?? "").ToString();
var searchText = txtSearchText.Text;
```

now I want to grab values from my repository using these values. I already have repository.GetBooks() which returns IEnumerable of books.

My question is how to define query with where clause having combo selection in mind.

```
var result = repository.GetBooks().Where(x=>x. ....)
```

obviously if ByTag is selected than this query should be `.Where(x=>x.Tag==comboSelection)`

Comment: If you only have three use cases, I wouldn't try to make this dynamic just for the sake of it. Just do an if-else flow on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your `ComboBox` has these items: `ByTitle`, `ByISBN`, `ByTag`. You should do something like the following:

```
//Use this Dictionary to get the corresponding delegate for the Where method
//Suppose your GetBooks() returns a collection of Book elements
Dictionary<Func<Book,bool>> predicates = new Dictionary<Func<Book,bool>>();
predicates.Add("ByTitle", b=>b.Title.Contains(searchText));
predicates.Add("ByISBN", b=>b.ISBN.Contains(searchText));
predicates.Add("ByTag", b=>b.Tag.Contains(searchText));

if(comboSelection != ""){
  var result = repository.GetBooks().Where(predicates[comboSelection]);
  //... other code
}
```

**NOTE**: Other approaches:

- Using `Reflection`, however your `ComboBox items` should have association with the corresponding `Property name`.
- Using `Dynamic LINQ`, you should search for more on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic Linq Library. After that you can write some thing like this

```
repository.GetBooks().Where("Tag == @0", comboSelection);
```

Comment: It can be ISBN instead of Tag or any other combobox selection.

Comment: You can create the whole string dynamically, based on what user has selected